# When working with a BST, can the left descendant of the right child of the root node be greater than the root node and visa-versa

Tags: binary-search-tree

[image]

When we are doing a BST, I understand that one major key point is that the left child must be less than the right child. Is it possible when we create a BST and have a root node, that as you traverse on the left side of that root node, and reach a right child of it, that right child is also greater than the root node?

Same thing if we were traversing on the right side of that root node. If we traverse on the right side of the root node, could we have a situation where we hit a left child that is less than the value of the root node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we are doing a BST, I understand that one major key point is that the left child must be less than the right child.

True, this is one of the things that follow from a BST structure.

> Is it possible when we create a BST and have a root node, that as you traverse on the left side of that root node, and reach a right child of it, that right child is also greater than the root node?

No, this is not allowed by definition.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) defines a BST as (I highlight in bold)

> ...a rooted binary tree data structure whose internal nodes each store a key greater than **all the keys** in the node’s left subtree and less than those in its right subtree.